# mongodb connection using mongoclient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following is my connection string

```
 uri= "mongodb://user:pass@host1:27017,user:pass@host2:27017/db?replicaSet=rs1"
```

I am using mongodbClient as follows to connect:

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
});
```

But I am receiving `Auth Failed Error`:

But when I connect to single instance like below

```
uri= "mongodb://user:pass@host1:27017/db" its working fine.
```

I am using mongodb ersion 3.0.1 and npm mongodb version ^1.3.23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format) shows this to be the URI format:

> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

In other words, you should only declare `username:password@` once:

```
uri = "mongodb://user:pass@host1:27017,host2:27017/db?replicaSet=rs1"
```